# AWS CopyImage how to specify destination region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, aws-ssm, aws-regions

I am trying to copy an ami to a different region than the source ami, E.g. copy and image from us-east-1 to us-east-2, and doing this via systems manager automation.
The [aws documentation says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CopyImage.html)

`To copy an AMI from one Region to another, specify the source Region using the SourceRegion parameter, and specify the destination Region using its endpoint.`

But the "request parameters" section doesn't show anything for destination region. Only "DestinationOutpostArn"

I have tried "DestinationRegion" but this has errored with:

`Error: updating SSM Document: InvalidDocumentContent: Unknown input names provided. Known=[ [ImageName, KmsKeyId, Encrypted, ImageDescription, ClientToken, SourceImageId, SourceRegion] ], Provided=[ [SourceImageId, SourceRegion, ImageName, Encrypted, KmsKeyId, DestinationRegion] ].`

So it doesn't recognise "DestinationRegion".

I can see "DestinationRegion" is also not listed in the aws:copyImage [automation documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-action-copyimage.html)

What is the endpoint the aws docs are referring to and how do I reference it? Or is it not possible to copy an image to a different region this way?

Comment: "The new AMI is copied to the region where you initiated the Automation action."